# Run console application with elevated permissions in MonoDevelop

Tags: permissions, mono, monodevelop, sudo

I would like to run a console application with elevated permissions. Running it from command line with sudo mono myapp.exe works but then I can't see a way to attach to the process for debugging. Is there a way to do this in MonoDevelop directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but nontrivial.

Setting the MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST environment variable will cause a new "Run->Run With->Custom Soft Debugger" command to show up in MD. You can use this to invoke the Mono debugger and connect it to MonoDevelop.

```
sudo mono --debugger-agent=${AgentArgs} yourapp.exe
```

Comment: When I invoke that custom soft debugger command in Mono 3.0.6, I get an Error dialog with a NullReferenceException (http://pastebin.com/vWdZA3u4).

Answer (score 0):

Run the whole of MonoDevelop with elevated permissions?

Comment: This works for me, but it's not an elegant solution because the final builds will be owned by root:root.